# .app created with cx_freeze instantly closing on launch

Tags: python, macos, cx-freeze

I am making a really simple app in python, using Tkinter as GUI, and cx_freeze to build it.
It all is in a simple "sleep.py" file.

The setup.py file used by cx_freeze is as follows :

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

executables = [
    Executable('sleep.py', base=None)
]

setup(name='Sleep Calculator',
      version='0.90',
      description='Sample cx_Freeze script',
      executables=executables
      )
```

The sleep.py file is launching correctly :
- When launched in MacOS from the terminal
- When built in MacOS using `python3 setup.py build`
- When built in Windows using `python3 setup.py build_exe` and then copying the tkinter files manually into the build folder created by cx_freeze

So I have a sleep.py file that is working both from Windows and Mac, a script that is working in MacOS, and an EXE that is working on Windows.

However, when trying to build to a .app using `python3 setup.py bdist_mac`, I get an app that is instantly closing on launch.

The only message I get during the launch, in the console, is
"Loading Preferences From User CFPrefsD For Search List"

During build, I get multiple 
`fatal error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/otool: internal objdump command failed`errors. Xcode is not installed, but CommandLineTools is.

I know almost nothing of OS X at the moment, so any help is welcome,
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where an app with cx_freeze would close as soon as I opened it, but running the executable inside the package would work.

It was solved for me by opening the built package and editing the info.plist file.

After adding a bundle identifier it started as it should.

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>My App</string>
```